# Generate PDF with Django Class Based Views

Tags: django, pdf, django-views

I currently have a Library Loan template implemented using Class Based Views. The implementation is probably something that we have seen before:

In `urls.py`:

```
#PK is the member ID  
url(r'^library/generate_loan_slip/(?P<pk>(\d+))/(?P<loan>(\d+))/'
        ,LoanSlipDetailView.as_view()
        , name='library_app_generate_loan_slip'),
```

In `views.py`:

```
class LoanSlipDetailView(DetailView):
    model = LibraryMember
    loan = None
    template_name = 'loan-slip.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context['loan'] = self.loan
        context['member'] = member
        return context

    def get_object(self):
        member = self.model.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        self.loan = LibraryLoan.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['loan'], for_member=member)
        return member
```

And in the HTML, `loan-slip.html`, the html with all the required variables in `{{}}` and controls using `{% if %} ... {% else %} ... {% endif %}` and `{% for ... %} ... {% endfor %}`.

Right now, I want the response to generate a PDF view. So far, I have checked out `reportlab` and they implemented it for function based views. However, is there an implementation for Class Based Views?

Answer (score -1):

You can just override get method of DetailView and write reportlab logic over there.

Comment: hello! could you give me more guidance in terms of the basics? just some code snippets to get me going. im sure this will be helpful to more than just me since it is a very common use case